# could not download httpclient.jar each time I press Try again

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

10:37 PM    Gradle sync started

```
10:37 PM    Gradle sync failed: Could not download httpclient.jar 
(org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.2): No cached version available 
for offline mode
Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (642 ms)
```

How to fix this bug?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to have configured a remote repository where the component is available. In this case https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient.

Gradle depends on the maven repository. You can define additional repositories either in your gradle script or globally in ${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml.

Answer (score 0):

This error comes when grade version is upgraded (as part of studio upgrade or stand alone). Check latest version and select that as part of settings here.

1- In Android Studio go to File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Gradle > Use local gradle distribution > then choose the latest version shown or new file (that you might have downloaded and unzip it) from your computer

2- Click Ok

3- Inside "build.gradle(Module:app)" make sure that compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion are same

8- Click Sync Now